# How to make unique lambda instances in C++? Or, how to set up id message handlers in xmpp with libstrophe?

Tags: c++, lambda, libstrophe

I'm using the [C libstrophe library](https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe) to make an xmpp application in C++11. I'm trying to register message handlers for specific IDs, so I can recognize a specific return message, using [xmpp_id_handler_add](https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe/blob/80a7ea0b7c645233319589a72fbb7b13d36fbb72/src/handler.c).

```
void xmpp_id_handler_add(xmpp_conn_t * const conn,
                         xmpp_handler handler,
                         const char * const id,
                         void * const userdata)
```

But there's something about strophe's implementation of this that I don't understand.

Strophe will only accept a function pointer of the form

```
typedef int (*xmpp_handler)(xmpp_conn_t * const conn, 
                            xmpp_stanza_t * const stanza, 
                            void * const userdata);
```

That's easy enough to do with a static function, but looking through the source code I find [this](https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe/blob/80a7ea0b7c645233319589a72fbb7b13d36fbb72/src/handler.c)

```
    /* check if handler is already in the list */
    item = (xmpp_handlist_t *)hash_get(conn->id_handlers, id);
    while (item) {
        if (item->handler == (void *)handler)
            break;
        item = item->next;
    }
    if (item) return;
```

Meaning that if I try to call xmpp_id_handler_add twice with the same static function, but a different id and userdata, it will reject the second call.

So I thought that maybe I could make a lambda every time I want to add a new ID handler, like so

```
auto msgHandler = [](xmpp_conn_t* const pConn, 
                     xmpp_stanza_t* const pStanza, 
                     void* const pUserdata) -> int
```

But when I looked at the pointer value of the lambda

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)((xmpp_handler)msgHandler));
```

And ran it twice, I got the same value both times. It seems the lambda is just like a static function in this case.

So, how can I make a new, unique function pointer every time I want to listen for a new ID? Alternately, am I misunderstanding how libstrophe is supposed to be used? Are you supposed to have a new static function for each new ID you want to listen for?

Comment: @Olaf my apologies, I thought they were relevant because libstrophe is written in C, and the answer to the question might be that I'm misunderstanding how to use xmpp

Comment: As I understand you ask about using a library from C++. It does not look like a question about the C language itself (resp. problems with that language). Similar for xmpp. The libaray-tag should be sufficient here. If an answer proves me wrong, feel free to add a tag (after all I'm not perfect and can err like every one else), but please refrain from adding in advance.

Comment: @RichardHodges I've got plenty of IDs, that's not the problem. The problem is that strophe does not allow you to use the same handler function twice, even if you use different IDs and userdata

Comment: @Sossisos hash_get(conn->id_handlers, id) returns handlers list for specific id, so it should not block you from using same function for different ids.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin the specific blocking line of code is "if (item->handler == (void *)handler)"

Comment: @Sossisos then how comes your handler is in list of handlers for different id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem has already been mentioned in the libstrophe issue tracker: https://github.com/strophe/libstrophe/issues/97. There is a patch in separated branch which is going to be merged to the master branch. Therefore, minor release `0.9.2` will contain it. The patch allows to add unique pairs of `handler` plus `userdata` instead of only `handler`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++14 you could create a generic lambda returning unique lambda (or rather lambda converted to static function) each time you call it:

```
auto msgHandlerCreator = [](auto X){ return +[](xmpp_conn_t* const pConn, 
                 xmpp_stanza_t* const pStanza, 
                 void* const pUserdata) -> int {/*...*/}; };
```

and call it each time with a different `std::integral_constant` e.g.:

```
msgHandlerCreator(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{})
msgHandlerCreator(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1>{})
```

Comment: This is a very clever idea, but unfortunately we only use C++11 :/ I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

In case of c++11 it won't be as easy to allow lambda to be declared inline but let's give it a try. We could create some helper struct to wrap our lambda but as unary `+` operator isn't constexpr (lambda has not linkage) we need to do some workarounds...:

```
template <class... Args>
struct voider {
    using type = void;
};

template <std::size_t, class, class = void>
struct FunctionWrapper;

template <std::size_t N, class L>
struct FunctionWrapper<N, L, typename voider<decltype(&L::operator())>::type>: FunctionWrapper<N, decltype(&L::operator())> {};

template <std::size_t N, class Res, class L, class... Args>
struct FunctionWrapper<N, Res (L::*)(Args...) const, void> {
    static Res (*l)(Args...);
    static Res foo(Args... args) {
        return l(args...);
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, class Res, class L, class... Args>
Res (* FunctionWrapper<N, Res (L::*)(Args...) const, void>::l)(Args...);
```

`FunctionWrapper` should now provide unique static function for each pair `std::size_t` x `Lambda`. Now function that will do actual wrapping:

```
template <std::size_t N, class L>
decltype(&FunctionWrapper<N, L>::foo) wrap(L &l) {
    FunctionWrapper<N, L>::l = +l;
    return &FunctionWrapper<N, L>::foo;
}
```

And we can enjoy unique function pointer for passed lambda as long as we provide unique id as a value known at compile time for each `wrap` call:

```
auto lambda = [](int x){std::cout << x << std::endl;};
std::cout << (void *)wrap<0>(lambda) << std::endl;
std::cout << (void *)wrap<1>(lambda) << std::endl;
wrap<0>(lambda)(1);
wrap<1>(lambda)(1);
```

Exemplary output:

> 0x400f28
>   0x400f76
>   1
>   1

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tzMy9YndrnSEnoIk)